# IdentityServer4 using Client Credentials Grant Type

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, claims

We are setting up an Identity Server 4 instance and one of the GrantTypes we wish to use is the Client Credentials Grant Type.

Is there a way we can link Client Credentials up to a use an AspNetIdentity user so we can get the claims and users details back for the client credentials provided?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

The Client Credentials grant type does not represent a user, it represents an application, so you would not use AspNetIdentity with the client credentials grant type.

If you want to include user specific claims you need to look at one of the grant types which involves user authentication.  Examples are available in the quickstarts [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/0_overview.html).  I would advise looking first at the Resource Owner flow and then the OpenID Connect based flows.

The quickstarts also include an example of integration with ASP.Net Identity, that can be seen [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html)